# best way to sum list items in e/Specman

Tags: specman, e

I created a list of structs and I like to sum the value of a field in each struct that satisfied a specific condition.
For example:

```
struct packet {
   val:int;
   cond:bool;
};
l:list of packet;
```

When I write the following:

```
keep l.all(it.cond).sum(it.val) == 1000;
I get an error: GEN_NO_GENERATABLE_NOTIF.
```

When I define a result variable:

```
sum_val : int;
keep sum_val == 100;
```

and change the constraint to:
    keep l.all(it.cond).sum(it.val) == sum_val;

I get a contradiction!

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the list pseudo method "sum" and the ternary operation:

```
keep l.sum(it.cond ? It.val : 0) == 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question it seems you want to sum some elements in existing list, not generate a new one. In this case, use simply :
var sum : int = l.all(it.cond).sum(it.val);